# Version number issue while submmiting app on appstore

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to submit my app  on app store.All step i understand well But little confusing about version Number.I have following query.

1- Is it compulsory to put version number numeric only like e.g- 1.0,1.1 etc?

2- Can we put any text instead numeric value on the version number like e.g- hair style, maintain body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)

It says this about the version number:

> Numbering should follow typical software versioning conventions (for example, 1.0 or 1.0.1, or 1.1).

"MyApp v.maintain body" makes no sense and cannot be compared for update notifications, etc.

Comment: i saw a app on app store there show version no is as text . you can see that app link http://itunes.apple.com/app/graciepowerdiet/id541869596?mt=8

Comment: Try it out if you want, but it makes no logical sense, looks ridiculous, and goes against the guidelines.

Comment: Thts why i confuse why apple allow this app. while app guideline not recommended it.